# ASP .NET Wizard Control and View State

Tags: asp.net, controls, viewstate, wizard

I have a form with 3 wizard steps, and when i click the button to dynamically add text boxes, that works fine, but when i go to the next step and i click on add to add more text boxes, it automatically adds all the text boxes from the previous steps and then continues to add if i keep click on it.

How do i prevent that from happening.

private List ControlsList
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["controls"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["controls"] = new List();
            }
            return (List)ViewState["controls"];
        }
    }

```
private int NextID
{
    get
    {
        return ControlsList.Count + 1;
    }
}


protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{

    string section = Wizard1.ActiveStep.ID;
    int sectionNum = Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex;

    var control = Wizard1.ActiveStep.FindControl("Place" + sectionNum) as PlaceHolder;

    base.LoadViewState(savedState);

    int count = 0;
    foreach (string txtID in ControlsList)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            control.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
        }
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        control.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
        txt.ID = txtID;
        control.Controls.Add(txt);
        control.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));

        count = count + 1;
        if (count == 3)
        {
            control.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));
            count = 0;
        }

    }
}


protected void AddControlButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string section = Wizard1.ActiveStep.ID;
    int sectionNum = Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex;

    var control = Wizard1.ActiveStep.FindControl("Place" + sectionNum) as PlaceHolder;

    TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();
    TextBox txt3 = new TextBox();


    txt1.ID = section.ToString() + "Size" + NextID.ToString();
    control.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
    control.Controls.Add(txt1);
    control.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
    ControlsList.Add(txt1.ID);

    txt2.ID = section.ToString() + "Description" + NextID.ToString();
    control.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
    control.Controls.Add(txt2);
    control.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
    ControlsList.Add(txt2.ID);

    txt3.ID = section.ToString() + "Quantity" + NextID.ToString();
    control.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
    control.Controls.Add(txt3);
    control.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
    ControlsList.Add(txt3.ID);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are storing all of the dynamic textboxes in `ViewState` and then the `ControlsList` property getter is returning the whole list when it is building the textboxes.

My recommendation is to use `Session` cache instead of `ViewState`, because it will allow you to differentiate the textbox controls from each of the wizard steps, like this:

```
Session["WizardStep1"] = listOfTextBoxesFromStep1;
Session["WizardStep2"] = listOfTextBoxesFromStep2;
Session["WizardStep3"] = listOfTextBoxesFromStep3;
```

Comment: Great idea, thank you for your response. I've never used sessions before, do you think you can help me and tell me where in my code I would need to modify in order to use sessions.

Comment: Are you storing these dynamically created text boxes to disk/database or is it a brand new experience every time the wizard is run?

Comment: Its a brand new experience every time the wizard is ran.